# An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available.

Tags: ios, xcode

I was creating new app id under my identifier tab .But i don't have any provision profile, certificate.Because this is my new apple account and registered with $99 yesterday.

But when i try to create app id for submission of my app to app store.I am getting this error:

```
An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available. Please enter a different string
```

What my doubt is?

1. should i need to create new build identifier in my xcode project.
2. I tried`XC.com.example,appname` - this work.If i do like this does my app build identifier will match with all certificate and provision profile??

Please help me to solve!!

Comment: if it is not available, it can be because someone might have already used that identifier for some other app. Always make it clean. "com.yourcompanyname.appname", or try like "com.yournickname.appname" so that it will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link below to create your provisional profile if you don't know how to do so:
http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-development-provisioning-profile

You can always modify which provisioning profile you want to use for your project in project settings.

In terms of build identifier: 
A typical bundle ID is set as follow: com.mycompany.appname. Taken from the developer.apple.com:

"A bundle ID precisely identifies a single app. A bundle ID is used during the development process to provision devices and by the operating system when the app is distributed to customers. For example, Game Center and In-App Purchase use a bundle ID to identify your app when using these app services. The preferences system uses this string to identify the app for which a given preference applies. Similarly, Launch Services uses the bundle ID to locate an app capable of opening a particular file, using the first app it finds with the given identifier. The bundle ID is also used to validate an app’s signature.

The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.). The string should be in reverse-DNS format. For example, if your organization’s domain is Acme.com and you create an app named Hello, you could assign the string com.Acme.Hello as your app’s bundle ID.

During the development process, you use an app’s bundle ID in many different places to identify the app."

Complete info can be found in below link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) may be helpful for you.

1)You can choose any app ID you like, but it is good to use your application name as the app ID, for the bundle name you should use the bundle identifier that is displayed in Xcode.

2)For app id suffix, you should choose a reverse domain name and the name should be your bundle identifier so that you can sign your project with the provisioning profile that use the app id.

3)it is good to use an name like a reverse domain name com.yourappname.*, but you can use the provisioning profile(after you generate it using the app id) only on the projects that have the bundle identifier name like the wildcard, so for example you can use the provisioning profile on an project that has the bundle identifier com.yourappname.miliondolarapp but you can't use the provisioning profile on a project with the bundle identifier com.myawesomeapp.miliondolarapp